# C# BsonDocument - How to check if field is an array

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, bson

I receive a BsonDocument whose structure I do not know. I go through all properties, but I want to handle arrays differently. How do I find out if the field is an array?

```
foreach(var property in bsonDoc){
   if(/**check if its an array field**/){
     //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Bson_BsonValue_IsBsonArray.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple, I guess I was a little confused. Nevertheless, I will post a solution.

As Eldar already commented there is a bool property that says if a BsonValue is a BsonArray:

```
foreach(var property in bsonDoc){
   if(property.IsBsonArray){
     //do something
  }
}
```

Here also works the is operator:
`property is BsonArray`

Which has the advantage that you can create a variable of the type at the same time, so I recommend this variant:

```
foreach(var property in bsonDoc){
   if(property is BsonArray arrayProperty){
     doSomething(arrayProperty);
  }
}
```